# Fetch / refresh object doesn't include the relation in the return

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an object "event", with a "participants" field contains array of pointer.
I want to refresh the object with the latest data from network

Refresh code:

```
event.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock() { event, error in

}
```

The problem is, method fetchInBackgroundWithBlock doesn't include the array of pointer field "participants" inside event object.

When I first get the object using query, I did

```
event.include("participants")
```

But when I refresh the object using method fetchInBackgroundWithBlock, I can't include the pointer field.

Is that possible to include the pointer field when refreshing object?

Comment: So it's an array of pointers rather than a relationship. Can you query for the specific object again? What is the trigger for the refresh?